# Compare two comma separated columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to compare two columns actual_data and pipeline_data based on source column bcz every source has different format.

I am trying to achieve the result column based on comparision between actual_data and pipeline_data .

I am new to pandas and looking for a way to implement this.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['pipeline_data'].str.len() == df['actual_data'].str.len(), 'Match', np.where(df['pipeline_data'].str.len() > df['actual_data'].str.len(), 'Length greater than actual_data', 'Length shorter than actual_data'))
```

The code above should to what you want to do.

Comment: ```df['result'] = np.where(df['pipeline_data'].split(",").len() == df['actual_data'].split(",").len(), 'Match', np.where(df['pipeline_data'].split(",").len() > df['actual_data'].split(",").len(), 'Length greater than actual_data', 'Length shorter than actual_data'))```                                                      Can we split on (",") and count no of fields ? I think series wont allow that

Comment: You could first split the content of the columns and save them back as a list